# Django middleware TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: django

I try to write a middleware in Django. And I get the error and I don't know why. There are the codes in the following:
setting.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'my.middleware.ReadedMiddleware'
]
```

middleware:

```
from  django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class ReadedMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self,req):
        pass
```

The information of error:

> mw_instance = middleware(handler)
>   TypeError: object() takes no parameters

According to other answers.If the middleware subclass from middlewareMixin rather than object, the error will be solved. But it did not work.

Here are the full errors:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
<_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace object at 
0x7f56cc6580f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lyg/pycharm-
2017.3.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 589, in 
__call__
return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 140, in 
 inner_run
handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
 File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", 
line 27, in get_handler
handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
 File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 65, in 
   get_handler
  return get_internal_wsgi_application()
File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 44, in 
get_internal_wsgi_application
  return import_string(app_path)
 File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
  module = import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in   
_find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in 
 exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/lyg/PycharmProjects/my/my/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
  application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
  return WSGIHandler()
File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 140, in __init__
 self.load_middleware()
File "/home/lyg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
  mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: can you share the full error message?

Comment: If you change *class ReadedMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin)* to class ReadedMiddleware(**object**) still get the same error ?

Comment: I show the full error in the question

Comment: Yes, actually I met the problem when the class subclass from the object.And then I change to middlewareMixin,but the problem is stll exist

Comment: Make sure you have saved the files and restarted the server after you have changed to `MiddlewareMixin`. Unless you are trying to adapt an old middleware which uses `process_request`, it would be better to start with the [`SimpleMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) example in the docs and adjust that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I find that there is another middleware.py in my project, so I did not change the class in my.middleware to MiddlewareMixin. And thank you for your django docs.I will read and adjust it